# Is it possible to parse real time data from JSON Volley Request?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm developing an android chatting apps for my web site. It will collect data from my web server. I'm using `JSON Volley` Parsing. Is it possible to parse real time data?? If possible please help me how??? If not is there any other api for this type of work???

Comment: what do you mean real time data?

Comment: means if any user send message to a user the targeted user will get tha message instantly.

Comment: JSON Volley is used to request a JSON, if you want the targeted user to get the message instantly you need to implement a mechanism for notifiying the user

Answer (score 0):

nope u can’t do this with volley.you have other ways-

> 1.Use firebase
>
> 2.Use Push notification
>
> 3.Or use Socket programming with Node.js

Comment: I also want store all msg to my web server and from my site if anyone send msg to anyone I want  it will appeared on the apps. means like facebook. Is it possible???  if possible what I have to do?? @Md.ibrahim Khalil.

Comment: yeap.its possible.It can be done by either firebase also by socket using your own server.If you think that your database may larger then you should use socket with your own server as firebase is not totally free

Comment: if o use firebase then I volley need or not?

Comment: Then how I get data from web server and how I update to web server?